# Accessing scope in ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple 1-page app design with two inputs in a static sidebar and an ng-view in which I load JSON data via a $http request in the controller. I'm using ngRoute to load different templates into the view.

This is sample code for my controller:

```
someModule.controller('JobPostingsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.cityFilter = function() {
    $http.get("dir/"+$scope.locationFilter+".json")
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.jobs = res.data;
        });
};

$scope.searchFilter = function (jobposting) {

    var keyword = new RegExp($scope.keyword, 'i');

    return !$scope.keyword || keyword.test(jobposting.title);

};

$scope.locationFilter = $scope.locationFilter || 'all';

 $http.get("dir/"+$scope.locationFilter+".json")
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.jobs = res.data;
    });
});
```

In my index.html I mark up the sidebar with the input fields that are models for locationFilter and keyword:

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" ng-model="keyword">
<input type="search" name="location" id="location" ng-model="locationFilter">
<button id="go" ng-click="cityFilter();">Click</button>
```

On load, the view displays the 'all' data normally and the searchFilter (based on the keyword model) works on the scope as intended.

However, when I click the cityFilter() button, the controller does get new data (if I do `console.log($scope.jobs)` inside my cityFilter() function, I see the intended JSON object in my console) but the view does not reflect these changes.

Why does the view reflect the changes in the keyword model, but not the cityFilter() changes? If the scope is different, as I first thought, shouldn't both be ineffective?

I set it up this way because I want the sidebar to be accessible from anywhere in the application. I am mostly confused by the fact that my controller seems to be aware of the changes to $scope variables but doesn't 'transmit' them to the view, even though ng-click is inside an $apply according to Angular documentation. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: The way my initial template is loaded using routeProvider:

angular.module('someModule', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',

```
function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

    .when('/', {

        templateUrl: 'dir/views/job-posting.html',

        controller: 'JobPostingsCtrl'

    })
...
```

The HTML for the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:searchFilter>
 {{ job.someProperty }}
</div>
```

The index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MasterCtrl">

    <div id="sidebar" ng-controller="JobPostingsCtrl">

            <input type="search" name="search" id="search" ng-model="keyword">

            <input type="search" name="location" id="location" ng-model="locationFilter">

            <button id="go" ng-click="cityFilter();">Click</button>

    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

Comment: don't see anything to do with `ngRoute` in your code.

Comment: You're going to have to post more of your html, but I suspect you are accessing different scopes. Try creating a parent object like so: `$scope.model={}' and then creating your jobs as a property on that object. This way,angular will travel up the chain to try and find the parent property and wont automatically create a new 'jobs' property on your current scope

Comment: @charlietfl, on closer inspection I don't think my problem will be of help for ngRoute so I have removed the tag. However I've updated my question with my routing configuration, which is how I'm loading the template using the controller. I think my problem is related to this.

Comment: @link64, I have posted more of my HTML and am trying your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: your problem is that each use of `JobPostingsCtrl` is a seperate instance. Suggest you implement a service to bind the data between controllers

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, that's what I thought - but I am curious as to how the `searchFilter` seems to work on both instances.

Comment: would need to see a working demo to understand that one

Comment: @charlietfl, in creating a Plunkr I realized it was because the model used in searchFilter was in the global scope, not in a different instance of `JobPostingsCtrl`. My issue is not yet resolved but this at least explains the inconsistency. Many thanks, anyway.